# Show cart using ajax

Tags: ubercart

In my website, I want when user click on add to cart to any product it will added automatically to cart via ajax and product should be visible on a cart text like 'Your shopping cart' and as i mouse hover on that link, the products which are in cart should be visble. How can i do this?? I am using ubercart.

Comment: Drupal 6 or Drupal 7?

Comment: Did you check https://drupal.org/project/uc_ajax_cart ?

Comment: drupal 7 and i checked it but it shows only a message..i want to update on a link. for eg- http://zeliahorsley.com/shop/ click on this link and add some product to cart and you will see on right top corner where is written 'Your shopping cart', the product appear there.

Comment: Any Answer? @AnilSagar